# Regex character case compatibility

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a regular expression that I suspect was originally written for the .NET Regex engine, that I'm trying to use in PHP. It contains the following character case which doesn't appear to be supported by PCRE (no match is returned, but there isn't an error):

```
[a-z-[cfx]]

preg_match('/[a-z-[cfx]]/', 'a'); => int(0)
preg_match('/[a-z-[cfx]]/', 'b'); => int(0)
preg_match('/[a-z-[cfx]]/', 'c'); => int(0)
preg_match('/[a-z-[cfx]]/', 'f'); => int(0)
preg_match('/[a-z-[cfx]]/', 'x'); => int(0)
```

I've checked [a cross-platform guide](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), but haven't been able to find out what this subcase actually does - is it `a-z` without `c` `f` and `x`? If so, what's the best way to write this in PCRE?

Comment: First of, what would you like to match ? Did you know that `a-z` alone would match all the letters from a to z. So `cfx` there doesn't make sense ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does indeed exclude characters from the outer character class. You can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CharacterClassSubtraction).

To achieve the same thing in PCRE, you can use something along the lines of `/[abdeg-wyz]/`.

Comment: Ah, it does now make sense **+1** !